# Is This a Compiler's Bug of Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-asio

I am writing a simple memcached client using boost asio, however, when compiled in release mode under visual c++ 2008 in Windows 7(64bit), the program will raise Access Violation exception if i add an innocent "std::string s;" in the function handler. Any suggestion is welcomed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>


typedef boost::asio::buffers_iterator<boost::asio::const_buffers_1> iterator_t;
typedef boost::iterator_range<iterator_t> range_t;
static const std::string LINE_END_MARK = "\r\n";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::streambuf _buf;
    std::ostream os(&_buf);
    os<<"END\r\n";

    iterator_t cursor = boost::asio::buffers_begin(_buf.data());
    iterator_t end = boost::asio::buffers_end(_buf.data());

    std::ostream_iterator<char> it(std::cout," ");
    std::copy(LINE_END_MARK.begin(), LINE_END_MARK.end(), it);

    range_t r(cursor, end);
    if(!boost::ends_with(r, LINE_END_MARK))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Probability that it's a bug in your code >>> probability that it's a bug in the compiler. Just sayin'.

Comment: If it's a compiler bug (and let's face it the odds are low compared to it being your code), narrow it down to a minimum example and submit a bug report

Comment: Try different IDE`s and see if you get the problem, most likely it'll be your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you add that "innocent" auto variable, you are changing the layout of the stack frame of that function. What happens is that some variable on the stack you are (always) corrupting gets moved. So when you were previously trashing some memory location that went unnoticed, you are now trashing something more important (like the return address).

Comment: the big while loop is actually not executed before the exception is raised, but if i comment the while loop, it will work as expected.

Comment: When it's executed doesn't matter. All local/auto/stack variables are collected during compilation and all allocated in the stack frame.  If you comment out the `while` loop, you are commenting out all of the real functionality of the function! It's no surprise that it "works" then.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Ball mentioned in the comments, the probability of a bug in your code is *much larger* than the probability of a compiler bug, especially with fairly recent compilers. If you're still convinced that it is a compiler bug, you could confirm your suspicions by compiling with another compiler (such as gcc or its Windows port, MinGW).

Comment: Of course, if the cause of the violation is UB (which it is here) it may seem to work on another compiler.

Comment: @EdS.: Turning up the compiler warnings might help find it, though. Did you find the bug?

Comment: UB = undefined behavior. Btw your code still has a problem, even if it isn't evident when compiled under g++. Try g++ -Wall and see if it gives you any helpful warnings.